# CSP Meta Tag incorrect: Blocking all fonts and JS

Tags: blazor-server-side, content-security-policy

I followed up on a different SO answer and updated my meta tag like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; https://*.googleapis/*/ https://*.fontawesome.com/*/ script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';">
```

My aim was to get FontAwesome to pass a CySec findings. However, the fix broke more than it fixed:

```
Ignoring duplicate Content-Security-Policy directive 'default-src'.

folio.dubaiairports.ae/:9 Ignoring duplicate Content-Security-Policy directive 'default-src'.

Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive '<URL>'.

mySite.myCompany.co/:9 Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'https://*.googleapis/*/'.

chext_driver.js:65 Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'https://*.googleapis/*/'.

mySite.myCompany.co/:1 Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

blazor.server.js:1 [2021-01-26T09:27:01.087Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://mySite.myCompany.co/_blazor'.
mySite.myCompany.co/:1 Refused to load the script 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/4f9675fbb7.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

mySite.myCompany.co/:1 Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Any helpful pointers will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [CSP has errors](http://csplite.com/csp/check/?pl=eJxtj8Fqw0AMRH9l2YvBEBsSSoN07L0U%2BgXqWrtRWe%2BaSElTQv69TmjAkFyE0AxPMwQbOOs8fJSTx3dUeAGf%2BcjZo8Aab9rb54eft%2FX2FfzAkQ7ZVroPrlHOsXEDGYFLNIHbmU0Kfa%2Bau6RGJqELdXTNoShFXvGRcoNO7TfzEnHXpWQpPDtGHoRujhadjOnxX6jFuBigexLpgXcP1nap1pSZJtG%2B7Rf3OPPoh7WOfI18FTXsZXrK%2Fe9Rv745LA3o8fIHsptwjg%3D%3D#result):

- a double `default-src` directives, the second one will be ignored.
- in the part `'unsafe-inline'; https://*.googleapis/*/ https://*.fontawesome.com/*/` the directive name is missed, therefore browser counts a `https://*.googleapis/*/` and `https://*.fontawesome.com/*/` host-sources as directive's names'. The `;` is a separator for directives, therefore after `'unsafe-inline';` a directive name should follow.
- `https://*.googleapis/*/` and `https://*.fontawesome.com/*/` have  invalid syntax because `*` is not allowed in the path-part or to cover top level domain zone, pls see [how to correctly specify host-source](https://csplite.com/csp4/).

I an not sure about `gap:` and `content:` scheme-sources, they not used in ordinary CSP, but they may be applicable in CSP for browser extensions.